# Can I locate element by pixel (css position)? Java, Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, element

```
public void ReorderColumns() {

// Element which needs to drag.
WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(
        "body > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.dynamic > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.dynamic.dynamic  > svg"));

Actions act = new Actions(driver);

// Drag and Drop by Pixel.
act.dragAndDropBy(From, 146, 214).build().perform(); }
```

I need to drag and drop an icon to reorder the column header on the web page, each header has its own reorder icon and there is no way to specify it by any Element locate methods(xpath/CSS selector/link..etc)
Is there any way to locate elements by the pixel(CSS position)?

Above is my code:

1. In CSS selector "dynamic" means those generated dynamically so that I don't want to use it.
2. But to perform the `act.dragAndDropBy` I need a WebElement parameter:

`dragAndDrop(source, target)`

`dragAndDropBy(source, xOffset, yOffset)`

3. 146, 214 is the position I want to drag the first reorder icon to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can help you to solve the problem:

```
    WebElement a = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your_selector"));
    WebElement b = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your_selector"));

    int x = b.getLocation().x;
    int y = b.getLocation().y;

    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(a)
            .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .clickAndHold(a)
            .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .moveByOffset(x, y)
            .moveToElement(b)
            .moveByOffset(x,y)
            .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .release().build().perform();
```